# How to post flash video like this on your facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, share

Ref : https://www.facebook.com/BMW.M/posts/999423980094632?pnref=story

I tried to post new msg with video url but look like the result it not to be like this.

I would like to know what technique they use. Please explain me if you know how to?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They shared the URL `http://www.eyesongigi.social/gigi-m` in this post, and that contains the Open Graph markup to embed the video.

What formats are supported and what tags you need, you can find here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#video

(And in case of any problems implementing it, use the [Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) first to check.)

Comment: Thanks a lot  to save my time. This is exactly answer for me. Thanks!